# What's the best practice to store secret information in memory in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, security, encryption, passwords

So the problem is that I have some secrets (TOTP/HOTP keys) that need to be used consistently by my program, but I don't want a memory dump to just show them all. I'm talking about common people whose computers can be compromised by malware.

If one thinks of encrypting these strings in memory with some symmetric encryption algorithm with a random bytes key, then it's probably harder than just reading the memory (AES-CBC, etc...), and this will require finding the random key in memory, then finding this data in memory that is decryptable with this.

Maybe I can make it even harder by splitting this key into multiple variables?

Well, I'm not a security specialist, and my question is to those who have faced this kind of problem before: What's the best practice to store secret information in memory? Is my concern legitimate, or is it paranoid, and all programs just put their passwords in memory?

Comment: Down-voters: Please suggest how to make this question better.

Comment: Just as educated guess: I suppose this is paranoid.

Comment: You may find more expertise at [Information Security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com) (e.g. [this related question](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/111651/securing-hsm-stored-symmetric-data-encryption-keys-aes-in-memory-on-server)).

Comment: @jdehesa Thanks. I'll read that, and if no one can help here, I'll consider asking there.

Comment: You have to think about the attack vector here. What kind of malware could find all Python interpreters from memory, go through all live Python objects to see which ones are strings, go through the storage of each string, and reliably guess which ones are meaningful secrets, but couldn’t just do the same with network sends or calls to a crypto library or whatever else you’re doing with the keys after decrypting them?

Comment: @abarnert Good question. I'm making a program that can utilize these keys. The library that utilizes those keys uses them only on call and doesn't keep traces on memory. So an attacker who sees the memory dump and that knows that my program exists will search for my program and could find it. This is what I'm thinking.

Comment: I have had to deal with the case where the app I’m working on is popular enough to attack specifically to find secrets used to encrypt an obfuscated protocol handshake in order to build a clone that speaks the same protocol. Any obfuscation we tried would have been cracked in a matter of weeks or months. So the answer was to come up with a better design that didn’t rely on that, and meanwhile add some obfuscation and change up the keys and obfuscation mechanism and handshake every couple months (and force the world to update) while weaning customers off depending on the old design.

Comment: @abarnert I see. So changing the encryption parameters in memory every now and then helps. I'll target that. Unfortunately, it's not possible to not rely on this information staying in memory for TOTP. The token is generated every 30 seconds, and the key is required for that.

Comment: OK, so you’re calling a library with these keys. You have to decrypt the keys, at which point they’re in memory—and, more importantly, you have to pass them to the library. Assuming the library is in C rather than Python, and you’re using an ABI binding to it like ctypes, the obvious way to break this is to hook `dlsym` or `FindProcAddress` and see what strings you pass to that library’s exports, rather than look at every string in memory.

Comment: @abarnert I gather that it's impossible to secure this as long as `ctypes` is involved...

Comment: Changing up the obfuscation scheme can help with some problems, but doing that blindly without evaluating the entire system is likely to be wasted effort that you could have spent on features, bug fixes, or fighting an attack vector that’s actually being attacked.

Comment: No, it’s impossible to obscure this as long as any boundary is involved. ctypes is just a guess at the easiest boundary you’re most likely to have based on your description. A real attacker will know what your program does and why and what libraries or servers it’s likely to be talking to, or he wouldn’t want to attack it, so he won’t have to make wild guesses.

Comment: @abarnert Would a C++ program that is totally statically linked into one executable solve all the problems that you can think of?

Comment: @TheQuantumPhysicist No. A program written in C++ with all encryptiion-related functionality not just statically linked, but spread out across multiple functions that also did other things at the same time, still didn't solve every problem we could think of. much less the ones we couldn't think of until the pirates thought of them first. The only solutions to this problem are a continuous arms race, or deciding that the arms race is not profitable.

Comment: There is a case I can think of where a one-shot solution is worthwhile: Sometimes, you want to be able to prove that you used an "industry standard" amount of protection for legal reasons when someone _does_ crack it. Maybe you want to defend yourself against lawsuits from a client, or to sue an upstart competitor, or to enforce some morally questionable but legally valid DMCA provision against pirates, or whatever. But then you just find out what's "industry standard", which probably means buying an off-the-shelf obfuscator and using it exactly as documented—but ask a lawyer.

Comment: @abarnert Thanks for the help and advice :-)

Comment: Depending on when and how your keys are used, you may want to look into using a https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hardware_security_module which is included in many modern devices. Also RAM encryption could be an option if you worry about a physical attacker. Minimizing the time the keys stay in RAM could also be helpful, but maybe hard in python. We would really need to know more of what you are ultimately trying to achieve with these keys to see if changing the protocol, so keys in memory are not that important, might very well be the better option.